# Is there a way to make this 'undefined' object safe?

Tags: prototypejs

On a page in a web app, a loading screen/widget continue to appear after the user leaves the text field.

The app is using version 1.6.0.3.  I looked at the most recent version of Prototype 1.7.3 and I did not find that function.

I also tested other instances when this method is called.  If there is no user input, the widget does not hang-up.

This error is displayed in the console of Chrome’s developer tools.

```
    at E (framework.pack.js:1699)
    at Function.stopObserving (framework.pack.js:1732)
    at A.hide (ui.pack.js:13410)
    at A.render (ui.pack.js:13591)
    at A.updateChoices (ui.pack.js:13650)
    at A.onComplete (ui.pack.js:13786)
    at Object.oncomplete (framework.pack.js:76)
    at framework.pack.js:2748
```

The specific method in questions seems to be in the Prototype.js file this =>

```
        if (element._prototypeEventID) return element._prototypeEventID[0];
        arguments.callee.id = arguments.callee.id || 1;
    return element._prototypeEventID = [++arguments.callee.id];
    }
```

I expect the loading widget to disappear after the save is done, but it is still on the page.  The console of Chrome's developer tools also has a second error:

```
validateFormCheck @ common.js:1031
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `getEventID` method is being called where the `undefined` warning/error triggers.

In version 1.6.0.3 `getEventID` is only called in `createWrapper` and `stopObserving`, I see stopObserving is in the call stack that you posted so let's go with that one.

`stopObserving()` takes 1 required parameter and 2 optional parameters (element, eventName, handler) if you only pass the element to the function it looks it up and then deletes all the PrototypeJS observers attached to that element. If you pass eventName and/or handler as well stopObserving will only specifically delete the observer you tell it to.

That being said, if the element is removed from the DOM before `stopObserving` is called this could cause the error you are seeing.

2 fixes that *could* work

- move the call to `stopObserving()` above the call to `remove()`
- comment out the call to `stopObserving()` and see if page behaves like you want it to